# php facebook application user wall post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am create a Facebook application. I am try to  post users wall.But i do not get any response

php code

```
 $user = $facebook->getUser(); 

if($user == 0) {



$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "publish_stream"));

echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");

} else { $token=$facebook->getAccessToken();

  try {     
  params = array(

            'message'       =>  "Hurray! This works :)",
            'name'          =>  "This is my title",
            'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
            'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
            'link'          =>  "http://stackoverflow.com",
            'picture'       =>  "http://i.imgur.com/VUBz8.png",
        );

        $post = $facebook->api("/me/feed","POST",$params);


  }
   catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $result = $e->getResult();
     }

  }
```

i can't post the content into user's wall .Please help me any one to debug the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I posted successfully on my FB using the following:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 

if($user == 0) {

//$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "publish_stream"));

//echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");

} else { $token=$facebook->getAccessToken();

  try {     
        $post = $facebook->api("/me/feed","POST",array(

            'message'       =>  "Hurray! This works :)",
            'name'          =>  "This is my title",
            'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
            'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
            'link'          =>  "http://stackoverflow.com",
            'picture'       =>  "http://i.imgur.com/VUBz8.png"
        ));
  }
   catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $result = $e->getResult();
     }
  }
```

If you haven't already, remember to include the facebook.php api and your code class initialization

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                                'appId' => APP_ID,
                                'secret' => APP_SECRET,
                                'cookie' => true
                            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

try post with php curl. if works your facebook class using rest api. Rest api deleted recently.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 

if($user == 0) {



$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "publish_stream"));

echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");

} else { $token=$facebook->getAccessToken();

  try {     
  $params = array(
            'access_token'  => $token,
            'message'       =>  "Hurray! This works :)",
            'name'          =>  "This is my title",
            'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
            'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
            'link'          =>  "http://stackoverflow.com",
            'picture'       =>  "http://i.imgur.com/VUBz8.png",
        );

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user.'/feed';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
            ));
              $result = curl_exec($ch);
              print_r($result);
              curl_close($ch);

  }
   catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $result = $e->getResult();
     }

  }
```

in your code params is not a $params.

Comment: {"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}  Error message is displayed ...

Comment: change url $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user.'/feed'; to $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user.'/feed?access_token='.$token;
if you get same error message, user has not accept publish_stream permission.